# iOS drum sequencer - Buffer issue (Bad access)

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio

I am making an 8 step drum sequencer using objective C. I am loading kick, snare, and hat samples into a buffer however, when the simulator runs and a switch is pressed to toggle a kick drum, I get a dreaded EXC_BAD_ACCESS error and the program quits.

After putting in a breakpoint, the debugg window suggests there is nothing in the buffer. But as far as i know, they are loaded here:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // laod the audio files into memory buffers
    _kickBuffer  = [PAEBuffer bufferNamed:@"TMD 09 KICK.aif"];
    _snareBuffer = [PAEBuffer bufferNamed:@"TMD 09 SN 1.aif"];
    _hihatBuffer = [PAEBuffer bufferNamed:@"TMD 09 CHH.aif"];

    // initialise the host
    _host = [PAEAudioHost audioHostWithNumOutputs:2];

    // create some channel strips to play the audio

    const int numVoices = 16;
    NSMutableArray* channelStrips = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:numVoices];

    for (int i = 0; i < numVoices; ++i)
    {
        PAEChannelStrip* channelStrip = [PAEChannelStrip channelStripWithNumChannels:2];
        [channelStrips addObject:channelStrip];
    }
```

The error appears in this function

```
-(void)playBuffer:(PAEBuffer*)buffer
{
    PAEBufferPlayer* player = [PAEBufferPlayer bufferPlayerWithBuffer:buffer];
    player.loop = NO;
    PAEChannelStrip* channelStrip = _channelStrips[_nextVoice];
    channelStrip.input = player;

    // we allocated voices in a round robin fashion, reallocating the oldest voices first
    _nextVoice++;

    if (_nextVoice >= _channelStrips.count)
        _nextVoice = 0;
}
```

I am new to this langauge so sorry If i haven't made everything clear. Any help is much appriciated, thanks.

(Edit) Added setStep Function

```
// the step has changed
-(void)setStep:(int)step
{
    if (step < 0 || step >= NUMSTEPS)
        return;

    _step = step;

    // decide which buffers to play on this step

    if (_kickSteps[step])
        [self playBuffer:_kickBuffer];

    if (_snareSteps[step])
        [self playBuffer:_snareBuffer];

    if (_hihatSteps[step])
        [self playBuffer:_hihatBuffer];
}
```

Comment: Is the `buffer` being passed in to `playBuffer:` `nil`?

Comment: Yes, in the debug window it says this player PAEBufferPlayer * nil 0x0000000000000000

Comment: Where do you call `playBuffer`?

Comment: In a setStep function  if (_kickSteps[step])
        [self playBuffer:_kickBuffer];

Comment: Please post the full code for `setStep`.

Comment: Is `_kickBuffer` valid after the first load?  How is it declared?  Is the `_kickBuffer` used in `setStep` the same variable that was loaded?

Answer (score 0):

The audio samples were in the build folder of the project but not in the 'supporting files folder' in Xcode. Issue resolved.